# display data between 2 dates in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date

How do I display data that is between two dates? I can only display data on one date.

This is my query:

```
 SELECT 
        (logs.user_activities.activity)::JSONB,
        logs.user_activities.created_at,
        sso.users.id,
        logs.user_activities.id_user,
        TO_CHAR(
    logs.user_activities.created_at,
    'TMDay, DD TMMonth YYYY HH12:MI PM')
      FROM
        logs.user_activities
        INNER JOIN sso.users ON (logs.user_activities.id_user = sso.users.id)
      WHERE
        sso.users.id = 21 AND
       (logs.user_activities.created_at)::date = ('2019-07-29')::date
      ORDER BY
        logs.user_activities.created_at DESC
```

if I want to display data between 2019-07-25 until 2019-07-30 how??

Answer (score 1):

```
  WHERE  sso.users.id = 21 
    AND  (logs.user_activities.created_at)::date BETWEEN ('2019-07-29')::date
                                                     AND ('2019-07-30')::date
```

But be careful, because you are using `::date` that mean `2019-07-30 23:00:00` count as `2019-07-30` so you are actually getting activities from day 29 and day 30.

If only want activities from day 29 you have to use

```
AND  (logs.user_activities.created_at)::date > = ('2019-07-29')::date
AND  (logs.user_activities.created_at)::date <   ('2019-07-30')::date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRUCT) and specify how you want the endpoints treated (included or excluded). In this case daterange which includes the 1st date and excludes the 2nd date;

```
(logs.user_activities.created_at)::date <@ daterange('2019-07-25', '2019-07-30', '[)')
```